# Какой программой открыть и прочитать файл .tad

Tags: файлы

Какой программой открыть и прочитать файл .tad ? База из программы cronos, покупалась еще в нулевых. Год назад слетела винда и программа перестала работать. Устанавливал новую, но он не грузит базу.

Comment: Предпоследнее сообщение посмотрите http://www.cronos.ru/cgi-bin/YaBB2/YaBB.cgi?num=1236245842 Если не поможет, то спрашивайте разработчиков на том форуме.

Comment: спасибо большое, это уже читал. Странно, что программа далеких 90-х, но до сих пор нет примочик для чтения баз в отдельной программе